# How to search with Regex for a string that starts with a defined string and ends with a defined string

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have the following string within a text file:

```
enable password dldjfgldfgdfg encrypted
```

I need to use Regex to determine if the pattern of "enable password " anything here " encrypted" exists.

I'm really green when it comes to regex, so any help is appreciated!  I tried:

```
/enable password/\s/./\s\encrypted
```

but it's not working.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably want the regex `/enable password .* encrypted/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
a = "enable password dldjfgldfgdfg encrypted"
puts a =~ /enable password .+ encrypted/
```

This should print 0, signaling that the string matches at position 0.

Comment: Do note that whitespace is not taken into account as a part of the "anything here".

Comment: true, gonna change that

Comment: That also matches `"enable password dldjfgldfgdfg encrypted pancakes"` even though it doesn't end with the requisite string.

Comment: @muistooshort The question doesn't specify whether the given string is an entire line. It just says "the string is in a text file".

Comment: But the title does: "starts with a defined string and ends with a defined string"

Comment: @muistooshort, your example: "enable password dldjfgldfgdfg encrypted pancakes" qualifies because the "enable password dldjfgldfgdfg encrypted" part matches the given requirement. It is a string (understand text file contents) that contains a string that starts with a defined string and ends with a defined string.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^enable password .+ encrypted$/
```

in regex, ^ is at beginning, $ is at the end

Comment: `^` is actually the beginning of line and `$` is end of line, `\A` and `\z` are beginning and end of string (respectively).